# file manipulation unix

Tags: unix

cat sample_file.txt(Extracted job info from Control-M)

```
upctm,pmdw_bip,pmdw_bip_mnt_35-FOLDistAutoRpt,Oct 7 2019 4:45 AM,Oct 7 2019 4:45 AM,1,1,Oct 6 2019 12:00 AM,Ended OK,3ppnc
upctm,pmdw_ddm,pmdw_ddm_dum_01-StartProjDCSDemand,Oct 17 2019 4:02 AM,Oct 17 2019 4:02 AM,3,1,Oct 16 2019 12:00 AM,Ended OK,3pqgq
```

I need to process this file into DB table(Oracle)
Bu I need to make sure that day is 2 number (example 7 to 07).
 (example: `Oct 07 2019 6:32 AM`)

I used this command to get all the date in every line:

```
cat sample_file.txt | grep "," | while read line
do
 l_start_date=`echo $line|cut -d ',' -f4`
 l_end_date=`echo $line|cut -d ',' -f5`
 l_order_date=`echo $line|cut -d ',' -f8`
 echo $l_start_date
 echo $l_end_date
 echo $l_order_date
done
```

Output:

```
Oct 7 2019 4:45 AM
Oct 7 2019 4:45 AM
Oct 6 2019 12:00 AM
Oct 17 2019 4:02 AM
Oct 17 2019 4:02 AM
Oct 16 2019 12:00 AM



expected output:

FROM: Oct 7 2019 6:32 AM
To:  Oct 07 2019 6:32 AM
```

I used this sed command but it add also to 2 number day (17)

```
sed command sed 's|,Oct |,Oct 0|g' sample_file.txt


Oct 17 was change to Oct 017

upctm,pmdw_bip,pmdw_bip_mnt_35-FOLDistAutoRpt,Oct 07 2019 4:45 AM,Oct 07 2019 4:45 AM,1,1,Oct 06 2019 12:00 AM,Ended OK,3ppnc
upctm,pmdw_ddm,pmdw_ddm_dum_01-StartProjDCSDemand,Oct 017 2019 4:02 AM,Oct 017 2019 4:02 AM,3,1,Oct 016 2019 12:00 AM,Ended OK,3pqgq
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry that I am interfering so much in your editing. I was trying to make the question easier to read. You should also remove your `SQL` tag from the question, since it is not really about SQL.

Comment: @cars10m sorry for that and thank you very much. I'm new here, that's why, I'm not familiar with the editing.

Comment: Done, I used this

sed 's/\([Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec]\) \([1-9]\) /\1 0\2 /g' sample_file.txt

How can I make this complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish it was easier, but I only managed the following:

awk.f:

```
function fmt(s) { 
  split(s,a," "); a[2]=substr(a[2]+100,2)
  return a[1] " " a[2] " "a[3] " " a[4] " " a[5]
}
BEGIN {FS=",";OFS=","}
      {gsub(/ +/," ");
       $4=fmt($4); $5=fmt($5); $8=fmt($8);
       print}
```

This is a little awk script that first removes superfluous blanks and then picks out particular columns (4,5 and 8) and reformats the second part of each date string into a two-digit number.

You run the script like this:

```
awk -f  f.awk sample_file.txt
```

output:

```
upctm,pmdw_aud,pmdw_aud_ext_06-GAPAnalysYTD,Oct 07 2019 6:32 AM,Oct 07 2019 6:32 AM,17,17,Oct 06 2019 12:00 AM,Ended OK,3pu9v
upctm,pmdw_ddm,pmdw_ddm_dum_01-StartProjDCSDemand,Oct 07 2019 4:02 AM,Oct 07 2019 4:02 AM,3,1,Oct 06 2019 12:00 AM,Ended OK,3pqgq
upctm,pmdw_bip,pmdw_bip_mnt_35-FOLDistAutoRpt,Oct 07 2019 4:45 AM,Oct 07 2019 4:45 AM,1,1,Oct 06 2019 12:00 AM,Ended OK,3ppnc
```

Comment: this awk fixed the problem, but they want me to use sed. hahahah but this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With a fixed locale, you can make a fixed replacement like

```
sed -r 's/(Jan|Feb|Oct|Whatever) ([1-9]) /\1 0\2 /g' sample_file.txt
```

Comment: Does the option `-r` work for you? Try small parts. like `sed  's/\(Oct\) \([1-9]\) /\1 0\2 /g' sample_file.txt`